# SwiftUI @ObservedObject:Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var editMode:EditMode = .inactive
    @ObservedObject var accetp = DataSource()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
              ForEach(accetp.accepted) { acceptd in
                    Text(
                        acceptd.number)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title2)
                    Text("\(acceptd.Carrier)")
                        .font(.title3)
                    var quex = acceptd.events[0]
                    Text("\(quex.description)")
                        .font(.title3)
                        }
            }.refreshable {
                self.accetp = DataSource()//the error:Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
            }
        
        }
    }
   

}
```

```swift
class DataSource:ObservableObject{
    @Published var accepted = Array<Accepted>()
    init() {
        gettrackinfoTrack()
    }
    // get data from URL
    func gettrackinfoTrack()  {
    cancellable = giphyProvider.requestPublisher(.gettrackinfo)
        .mapString()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            guard case let .failure(error) = completion else { return }
            print("查询错误:\(String(describing: error.errorDescription))")
        }, receiveValue: { response in
            //print("数据：\(response)")
//                var b1=Array<Accepted>()
            if let data = response.data(using: .utf8) {
             if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
                 let context = json["data"]["accepted"]
                 for (i,subJson):(String, JSON) in context {
                     print("key = \(i)");
                     print("val = \(type(of: subJson))");
                     if let acceptd = Accepted.accepted_Build(json: subJson, events: Question.build(json: subJson)!){
                         print("这是我的数据\(String(describing: acceptd.events)),\(String(describing: acceptd.number)),\(String(describing: acceptd.Carrier))")
                         self.accepted.append(acceptd)
                     }
                       
                 }
                 
             }
            }
           
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

I have tried many methods and I still can't solve this problem:

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

Comment: Unrelated, but note that you should be using `@StateObject var accetp = DataSource()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struct's are immutable. The usage of `@ObservedObject` is not how you are doing it.

**The concept is in simple words**: When you update `@Published` property (`accepted`) in any `@ObservableObject` conformed class(`DataSource`), the view (`ContentView`) which is holding the `@ObservedObject` will refresh/reload the view.

So you should update your code as follows:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var editMode:EditMode = .inactive
    @ObservedObject var accetp = DataSource()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
              ForEach(accetp.accepted) { acceptd in
                    Text(
                        acceptd.number)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title2)
                    Text("\(acceptd.Carrier)")
                        .font(.title3)
                    var quex = acceptd.events[0]
                    Text("\(quex.description)")
                        .font(.title3)
                        }
            }.refreshable {
                // This will update your DataSource's `accepted` property
                // As `accepted` property is @Published so the view will also reload
                self.accetp.updateTrackingInfo()
            }
        
        }
    }
}

class DataSource:ObservableObject{
    @Published var accepted = Array<Accepted>()
    init() {
        gettrackinfoTrack()
    }
    
    // Call this function to reload your `accepted` data, 
    // which will reload the view also as the property is @Publisher
    func updateTrackingInfo() {
        accepted = [] // Clear the array as you want to fetch data newly
        gettrackinfoTrack()
    }
    
    // Make this private
    // get data from URL
    private func gettrackinfoTrack()  {
    cancellable = giphyProvider.requestPublisher(.gettrackinfo)
        .mapString()
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            guard case let .failure(error) = completion else { return }
            print("查询错误:\(String(describing: error.errorDescription))")
        }, receiveValue: { response in
            //print("数据：\(response)")
//                var b1=Array<Accepted>()
            if let data = response.data(using: .utf8) {
             if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
                 let context = json["data"]["accepted"]
                 for (i,subJson):(String, JSON) in context {
                     print("key = \(i)");
                     print("val = \(type(of: subJson))");
                     if let acceptd = Accepted.accepted_Build(json: subJson, events: Question.build(json: subJson)!){
                         print("这是我的数据\(String(describing: acceptd.events)),\(String(describing: acceptd.number)),\(String(describing: acceptd.Carrier))")
                         self.accepted.append(acceptd)
                     }
                       
                 }
                 
             }
            }
           
        })
    }
}
```

I have added comment on the code for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI views are immutable structs, only state variables can be modified.

By setting `accetp` (presumably should be `accept`) to a new instance of `DataSource` inside the `refreshable` block, despite already having initialized it, you are modifying the value of an immutable property on the struct.

Looks like what you'd want to do is call a function on the `DataSource` instance to trigger it to get data again.

e.g.

```
.refreshable {
    self.accetp.gettrackinfoTrack()
}
```

Since `accetp` is marked with `@ObservedObject`, when its published variable `accepted` is modified your `ContentView` will update accordingly.